# Azure File Service shared drive with System.IO not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have several VM's in Azure that use the same data (pictures etc), that are stored in a storage account with a File Service setup.

I ran the commands mentioned in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/ to mount the drive on the VM's and persist the credentials.

From my c# code however I keep getting exceptions that the path cannot be found.

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'X:\Data\test'.
```

Comment: Did you verify that X: was mapped correctly within the VM for all users?

Comment: Did you ensure that the credentials are stored for the same user context the C# code is running under?

Comment: I set the app pool identity tot the same user as I'm running the VM with.

Comment: Eventually this answered it for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25621494/2713516